# How does "caffeinate" affect the remaining power adapter display turn-off delay?

Tags: sleep-wake, power

I'm running Big Sur 11.7.3.

I know that the `caffeinate` utility can prevent the system from going into power-saver mode. But what I want to know is whether after `caffeinate` runs, will the power-saver display turn-off delay now be reset to its original value, or will the remaining time until display turn-off continue to decrement even when `caffeinate` is running?

For example ...

Suppose that my power-saver "Turn-off after" delay is set to 120 minutes.

At 7:00 AM, I run the following command in order to prevent system idle for 80 minutes, and I do not interact with my machine at all ...

```
caffeinate -udist 4800
```

At 8:20 AM, that `caffeinate` command will terminate. Now, assume that I continue not to interact with my machine. At 8:20, will my power-saver turn-off time be 120 minutes in the future from that point (at 10:20 AM), or will it now be 40 minutes in the future from that point (at 9:00 AM), because it originally started counting down from 120 minutes at 7:00 AM?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to run some tests, and it turns out to be the opposite of the assumption. In other words, after the `caffeinate -udist ...` power assertion, the power timeout resets.

I set my "Turn display off" timer to 60 seconds, and then I ran the following script without interacting with my Mac at all:

```
while true
  caffeinate -udist 2
  sleep 43
done
```

In other words, when this script is running, the 2-second power assertion gets issued every 45 seconds. In this case, my Mac never goes to sleep.

This means that the display must indeed be getting reset to turn off one minute after each power assertion.

Answer (score 0):

## Unspecified Behaviour

This behaviour is not formally specified by Apple and may change between versions of macOS.

You will need to run an experiment to determine the impact of a [power assertion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1557134-iopmassertioncreatewithname) (such as those created by [`caffeinate`](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/caffeinate/)) on the timing.

### Likely Approach

I expect the power assertion will not affect the timing but this is an assumption.

I assume this behaviour because maintaining constantly adapting timers is expensive. A less computationally demanding approach is to:

1. Determine the next possible idle time;
2. Wait the full duration;
3. Then check if the conditions are met at that moment:

   - If met, reduce power;
   - If not met, recalculate based on the current idle time.

This approach does not need to track the creation and removal of power assertions.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my assumption, as well. I am not near my Mac for a while, which is why I asked here instead of testing the assumption myself. Later this week, I'll test the assumption.

Comment: I was able to run a test, and it turns out that the assumption is not correct. See my answer, above.

Comment: Thank you testing and sharing the results. If you change versions of macOS, be sure to re-run the test. Apple are increasingly assertive over power saving.

Comment: Thank you. I will indeed re-run my test when I upgrade MacOS.